# How to configure a minimum app version for an iOS app React-Native

Tags: ios, react-native, app-store, app-store-connect

I want all users off my app to stay above a minimum threshold version. Is there a way I can configure it either in the code or app store that invalidates the users on a certain version and redirects them to the app store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have already an application that in the production and installed to devices.

In this case, unfortunately you can't put version limit on them. The only way is, deprecating v1 APIs and creating v2 APIs. The older version app owners will get a warning (If you well made the error handling.).

Otherwise, you can add a new feature like checking the version on the startup of the application. And If it is older, you can show a message like "Please update the application." and put a button that redirects to the AppStore.

[image]
*(The image is from a Medium blog post named ["Mandatory Update for your apps"](https://medium.com/nextfaze/mandatory-update-for-your-apps-b99b0d4c36d6).*

I don't recommend forcibly redirecting users to AppStore. It is not a great UX practice. You can block the screen of the application with the warning but at least leave the basic functionalities open.

Comment: isn't creating a blocking flow against app store guidelines?

Comment: There are already some of the games doing this to make sure the in-game playground or game rules are up to date for everyone. On the other hand, some apps kindly requiring users to update the app. But, I'm not sure about that AppStore guideline about blocking the flow.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/107576
In this thread people have stated that the user can't be forced to upgrade.
My confusion is that is there any way we can actually "force" this upgrade thing :/

Comment: Unfortunately, there is not any other way except these options.